# How to capture just the ip address string using vb script

Tags: vbscript

Sorry I am new to programming need some kind people who can help me on this...

I have a list of information below i want to use vb script to get just the ip address number string how to do it???

mac address               ipaddress          name           interface  flags

00:87:90:65:67:98   192.165.32.23     192.165.32.23    vlan.10   none

Comment: Are you using VBScript, VBA, VB.NET, or VB6 (or some earlier version)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
strYourInput = "00:87:90:65:67:98 192.165.32.23 192.165.32.23 vlan.10 none"
strIP = Split(strYourInput, " ")(1)
```

Basically, it splits the input string into an array based on the space character (" ") and then references the element at index 1 (since arrays are zero-indexed, it's actually the second element).

Comment: I would highly recommend using "\s+" as the pattern for splitting - to split on one or more white spaces.  Also, adding the limit option of 3 would speed things up a little.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VB.NET, as the tag on your question implies, you can use the `String.Split` method, like this:

```
Dim data As String = "00:87:90:65:67:98 192.165.32.23 192.165.32.23 vlan.10 none"
Dim fields() As String = data.Split(Nothing)
Dim ipAddress As String = fields(1)
```

If, however, you are using VBA or VBScript, that's a different story...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you may want to know the nature of your output. You need to know how to validate a string for an IP Address.

Elements of IP Address will become the conditions you need to test againts.

1. 4 segments
2. separated by dot delimiter
3. each segement's number span from lower bound => 0 to upper bound <= 255

That's the basic. But in reality following is [used to validate an IP address](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/vba/validate-ip-address-vba/):-

```
The first number cannot be 10.
If the first number is 172, the second number cannot be between 16 and 31 (inclusive).
If the first number is 192, the second number cannot be 168.
None of the numbers can be greater than 255.
```

In my sample codes, I am not going to follow rigours IP validation arguments but basics.

If you are using VBA, you can still use `Split` method. Check on [Split documentation here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
When using `Split`, there's a delimiter you can use. Which can be a anything from [a-z] to [0-9] to special characters [,;'@]...

Option Explicit

```
Sub validateIP()

Dim strTrash As String
Dim varDelimited As Variant
Dim varDotDelimited As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, trueCounter As Integer

'--in your case in between each of the IP address and other combinations, has a white space
strTrash = "00:87:90:65:67:98 192.165.32.23 192.165.32.23 vlan.10 none"

'--first delimit by white space using Split
varDelimited = Split(strTrash, " ")

'-- loop through variant array
For i = LBound(varDelimited) To UBound(varDelimited)
    '--validate if delimited strings are starting and ending with a number and if string contains a dot
    If IsNumeric(Left(varDelimited(i), 1)) And IsNumeric(Right(varDelimited(i), 1)) And InStr(varDelimited(i), ".") Then
       '--validate for IP address type
        '--delimit by dot
        varDotDelimited = Split(varDelimited(i), ".")
        '--validate for 4 segments : Split results in zero-indexed arrays
        If UBound(varDotDelimited) = 3 Then

            '--set trueCounter to zero
            trueCounter = 0

            '--validate each segment for a number between 0 and 255
            For j = LBound(varDotDelimited) To UBound(varDotDelimited)
                If IsNumeric(varDotDelimited(j)) And CInt(varDotDelimited(j)) >= 0 And CInt(varDotDelimited(j)) <= 255 Then
                        '--you can either save data into an array or any collection object and dump them later on to sheet
                        '--or simply throw a message box each time you find a valid IP address from Trash
                        trueCounter = trueCounter + 1
                End If
            Next j

            If trueCounter = 4 Then
                MsgBox varDelimited(i) & " is a valid IP Address"
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

---

**Another way to validate is by using `Regex`.** You can check on that later on if you are interested in.

```
Sub validateIPRegex()
Dim strTrash As String
Dim objRegEx As Object
Dim matchedIPs As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim allIPs As String

    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegEx.Global = True
    objRegEx.MultiLine = False
    '--this pattern doesn't consider 255. Just any 1 to 3 digit number between 0-9
    objRegEx.Pattern = "(\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b)"

    strTrash = "00:87:90:65:67:98 192.165.32.23 192.165.32.25 vlan.10 none"
    If objRegEx.Test(strTrash) Then
        Set matchedIPs = objRegEx.Execute(strTrash)
    End If

    If matchedIPs.Count <> 0 Then
        For i = 0 To matchedIPs.Count - 1
                allIPs = allIPs & " " & matchedIPs.Item(i)
        Next i
    End If

    MsgBox allIPs
End Sub
```